# How to associate file types with wine in nautilus

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, wine, file-association, file-type

I have Ubuntu 12.10 with Nautilus 3.4.2.

After installing wine "apt-get install wine" are exe files still associated with the archive manager.

In previous versions of ubuntu I've always right clicked on the file, choose Properties > Open with > Select an application to open ... > Wine.

But since version 12.04 Wine in Programs menu is missing.
I tried it on a laptop and PC, version 12.04 and 12.10.

I found a workaround: 
http://vazhavandan.blogspot.cz/2012/12/nautilus-342-open-as-administrator-hack.html

But I wanted to find a correct solution, Im installing ubuntu to users, and I'd like at everything works as it should.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alacarte to add the necessary program to the list.
Works in 12.04 + 12.10

Moreover, will allow you to comfortably add your own shortcuts to the dash.

sudo apt-get install alacarte -y ; alacarte

Answer (score 6):

In ubuntu 13.04 The wine is designed to be hidden, defined in the wine application launcher property `NoDisplay=true` in `/usr/share/applications/wine.desktop` file. You're not supposed to disable this property.

To install (and uninstall) windows application you just need open the **Dash Home** and type **wine** in searching box. You will see **"Uninstall wine Software"** icon. Click on it to open the window and you will see **"Install"** button. Run the window installer using this.

During the installation, wine will automatically create ubuntu application launcher file (*.desktop) at `~/.local/share/applications/`.

After installation you will able to launch the window application from **Dash Home** - just type the name of application on the searching box, you will see the icon of the application is appeared, if you see nothing, try to log off and log on then try again. Once the application is launched, you can lock the icon on the launcher (just right click on the icon and click "Lock the launcher").

In case you want the window apps available in the **"Open with"** application list, you  just need to add **`%U`** in the `"Exec"` property of the application launcher file (*desktop).
This is a snippet of my notepad++ application launcher (`~/.local/share/applications/wine-Programs-Notepad++-Notepad++.desktop`), I add`%U` at the end so I able to open any file using Notepad++:

```
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/ ... Programs/Notepad++/Notepad++.lnk %U
```

---

**NOT RECOMMENDED**

In case of you are insist to be able to launch windows application directly from Files(aka Nautilus), ie: portable application,  you can add the following line into `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

```
application/x-ms-dos-executable=wine.desktop
```

This configuration will cause the `*.exe` file is launched when you are double click the file, similar the cli command

```
$ wine some_app.exe
```

PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS METHOD TO LAUNCH THE WINDOWS INSTALLER.

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick one *.exe and choose open with, then select wine programloader and select 'set as standard application'

Comment: That's what has worked until recently.
But as I write, since version 12.04 is there no longer wine programloader item.

http://i50.tinypic.com/nlwufm.png

http://i49.tinypic.com/axqw1.png

Comment: I'm using 13.04 at the moment and I have the wine loader. Strange

Comment: Same problem with java loader.

Comment: But I found a solution. alacarte help you add a program to the list and then I can associate it with extensions

Answer (score 0):

Install alacarte, and the browse in alacarte to get the command for the windows program.

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/bisht/.wine" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/bisht/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\ Menu/Programs/Notepad++/Notepad++.lnk
```

Now open the filetype you want and add this command and if you want set it as default.

This would open the filetype by default with windows program set as default.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
I did not need any of the external applications. Here is what I did.

1. Right click on the exe
2. Open with > Other Application
3. DOUBLE CLICK on "Wine Windows Program Loader"

Now .exe is associated with wine.